# Android BindingAdapter error.NonExistentClass

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

Here it is my BindingAdapter

```
@InverseBindingMethods({
        @InverseBindingMethod(type = RecyclerView.class, attribute = "lastAdapter", method = "getLastAdapter"),
})
public class RecyclerViewBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter(value = {"lastAdapter"}, requireAll = false)
    public static void setLastAdapter(RecyclerView view, LastAdapter adapter) {
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "lastAdapter")
    public static LastAdapter getLastAdapter(RecyclerView view) {
        return (LastAdapter) view.getAdapter();
    }
}
```

I have added RecyclerView dependency on my gradle:

```
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1"
```

Here it is how I use in my layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 app:lastAdapter = "@{viewModel.adapter}"
 ... />
```

I have already set the viewModel binding variable after inflating this layout. But whenever I run my codes, gradle always shows the following error

```
Error:(48, 34) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:lastAdapter' with parameter type error.NonExistentClass on android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.
```

I can resolve this problem by removing any `app:lastAdapter` from my layouts then clean and rebuild, rewrite those `app:lastAdapter` attibutes again then rebuild project, everything works fine.

That is not a convenient solving.

Comment: What does your variable line look like? And what is the `adapter` in your ViewModel?

Comment: Hi George, `adapter` is an object from LastAdapter class 
here it is
`var adapter = LastAdapter(data, BR.item).map<MenuLinked, MenuItemBinding>(R.layout.menu_item) `

Comment: Your BindingAdapter takes a `LastAdapter`, but adapter appears to be a different type. Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Take a look at that `adapter` is implicitly declared as `LastAdapter`. Is it possibly because the type is not declared explicitly? Let me try it

Comment: Thank you George. That's it, BindingAdapter can't determine the type due to Kotlin implicit type assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As George said at the comment above **"BindingAdapter takes a LastAdapter, but adapter appears to be a different type"**
and this is how the variable asigned:

```
var adapter = LastAdapter(data, BR.item).map<MenuLinked, MenuItemBinding>(R.layout.menu_item)
```

It seems DataBinding library can't determine implicit data type declaration from Kotlin, so it need to be defined explicitly:

```
var adapter : LastAdapter = LastAdapter(data, BR.item).map<MenuLinked, MenuItemBinding>(R.layout.menu_item)
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this command inside android studio terminal and build project again

./gradlew clean assemble